# How to disable pan mode for certain view controllers in the MFSideMenu class?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm using the MFSideMenu from [github link](https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu/blob/master/README.mdown) in my project. It's working, however I would like to disable it in a certain viewcontroller.

I added this in the viewcontroller but it doesn't disable the panMode:

```
#import "MFSideMenuContainerViewController.h"

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    MFSideMenuContainerViewController *sideMenu = [[MFSideMenuContainerViewController alloc] init];

    sideMenu.panMode = 0;

}
```

my plan was then to re-enable the panmode in the viewDidDisappear method.

FYI in the `MFSideMenuContainerViewController.m` file if I add `self.panMode = 0;`
 to the `- (void)setDefaultSettings {self.panMode = 0;}` it does disable the menu pan except it disables it for the entire app of course.

I must not be referencing the `MFSideMenuContainerViewController` property panmode correctly.

in my AppDelegate:

.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container;
```

.m

```
  MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = [MFSideMenuContainerViewController
                                                    containerWithCenterViewController:self.navController
                                                    leftMenuViewController:nil
                                                    rightMenuViewController:rightSideMenuController];

    self.window.rootViewController = container;
```

thanks for any help

Comment: In .m file you should not define new container variable. Instead of doing it use self.container and assign the object. after that set self.container to rootViewController. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are four different MFSideMenuPanModes.

You can try with the following statement.

In AppDelegate.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container;
```

In AppDelegate.m - didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method

```
 self.container = [MFSideMenuContainerViewController
                                                containerWithCenterViewController:[self navigationController]
                                                leftMenuViewController:leftMenuViewController
                                                rightMenuViewController:rightMenuViewController];
```

In your View Controller - viewWillAppear method.

```
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
delegate.container.panMode = MFSideMenuPanModeNone;
```

Comment: I tried that. It's the same as "panMode = 0;" It works when I change it in the MFSideMenuContainerViewController.m directly but not in the other view controller. thanks for your post though.

Comment: Even though you are in different view controller, can't you get a reference to 'MFSideMenuContainerViewController' object from AppDelegate and assign this panMode?

Comment: I get "container" is not found on object of type AppDelegate. Should that object be there? The menu is working fine without that. I just can't disable it from another vc. thanks again!

Comment: I have it set up exactly like that. I edited my code above. Could this line be throwing it off.   self.window.rootViewController = container; in the AppDelegate be the reason it doesn't work in the other vc?

Comment: You need that statement. But it should be like this. self.window.rootViewController = self.container;

Comment: it worked! I had to synthesis the property and then added the "self." to "container" as in    self.window.rootViewController = self.container; big thanks for all your help! :)

Comment: Also, you need to re-enable the panning in viewWillDisappear method. delegate.container.panMode = MFSideMenuPanModeDefault

Answer (score 11):

You can use this in `viewWillAppear`.

```
[self.menuContainerViewController setPanMode:MFSideMenuPanModeNone];
```

Comment: It is working fine in viewWillAppear method only. Not working in viewDidLoad method.